# Dynamic per REST(Jersey) request binding of configurations in Guice

Tags: java, binding, dependency-injection, jersey, guice

We are using Guice in our project for DI. Currently we have some configurations(properties) that we load a t server startup from a file. These are then bound to all the components & used for all the requests.

But now, we have multiple property files & load them at startup. These configurations can be different per REST(Jersey) request as they depend on the input.

So, we need to bind these configurations dynamically for each request. I looked into Guice API for `@RequestScoped`, but did not find anything specificallyu helpful.

There are few questions similar to this, but no luck yet. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Are you using any sort of plugin to make Guice aware of Jersey? Otherwise, you'll need to use the DI in Jersey to get access to request scoping.

Comment: Why don't you make use of ContainerRequestFilter to filter all incoming requests. Populate this configuration object and set it in the request Object back.

Comment: @BandiKishore  - Can you give me a reference to some implementation for the same? That would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm providing 2 ways of doing this and both are request scoped.

1. Using `HttpServletRequest`, for classes where you can Inject request object.
2. Using `ThreadLocal`, Generic way. It can be used in any class. 
   (**NOTE**: This method wouldn't work if your creating new threads in your code and want to access the value. In which case you'll have to pass the values through Objects to those threads)

I meant something like this:

```
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest      request;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        List listOfConfig = //load Config;
        request.setAttribute("LOADED_CONFIG",listOfConfig);

        // If you want to access this value at some place where Request object cannot be injected (like in service layers, etc.) Then use below ThreadLocals.
        ThreadLocalWrapper.getInstance().get().add("adbc"); // In general add your config here, instead of abdc.
    }
}
```

My ThreadLocalWrapper looks like this:

```
public class ThreadLocalWrapper {

    private static ThreadLocal<List<String>> listOfStringLocals; // You can modify this to a list of Object or an Object by itself.

    public static synchronized ThreadLocal<List<String>> getInstance() {
        if (listOfStringLocals == null) {
            listOfStringLocals = new ThreadLocal<List<String>>() {
                @Override
                protected List<String> initialValue() {
                    return new ArrayList<String>();
                }
            };
        }
        return listOfStringLocals;
    }
}
```

**To Access the value:**

**In Controller** - Inject `HttpServletRequest` Object and do getAttribute() to get the value. Since `HttpServletRequest` Object is requestScoped, you can set the loaded config. into this and access it in your controller's using request Object again.

**In Any other part of the code** - If `HttpServletRequest` is not available then you can always use the ThreadLocal example shown. To access this value.

```
public class GuiceTransactionImpl implements GuiceTransaction {

    private String value = "";

    public GuiceTransactionImpl(String text) {
        value = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String returnSuccess() {
        return value + " Thread Local Value " + ThreadLocalWrapper.getInstance().get();
    }

}
```